# Grunt - Mapreduce Mode: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximum

Tags: mapreduce, gruntjs, apache-pig

I'm running a mapreduce mode in Apache Pig version 0.17.0 to simply dump a few lines of text data from a file on HDFS Hadoop-2.7.2

When executing the `dump` command, the execution goes very slow, however it gets completed. I see some failures during execution shown below:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1589604570386_0002]
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
[main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1589604570386_0002]
[main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
[main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
[main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
[main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats - Failed to get map task report
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:184)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.getTaskReports(MRJobStats.java:528)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addMapReduceStatistics(MRJobStats.java:355)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:232)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:164)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:379)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1475)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1460)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:995)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:782)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Is there away to speed up the mapreduce job?